# Multiple line grep enclosed by two dates

Tags: regex, grep

In a log file:

```
...
Fri Jan 24 12:33:56 +0800 2014
11 files processed.
56471 records inserted.
Fri Jan 24 12:36:56 +0800 2014
...
...
Sat Jan 26 12:36:25 +0800 2014
13 files processed.
62471 records inserted.
Sat Jan 26 12:37:56 +0800 2014
...
```

I'd like to get the value `13` in `13 files processed.` for a certain date (`Jan 26 2014`). How can that be done via command line grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk solution:**

```
awk '/Jan 26/{p=1;next} p{p=0;print $1}' file
13
```

**grep only solution:**

```
grep 'Jan 26' -A 1 file | grep -oP '[0-9]+(?= files processed)'
13
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other `awk` variations:

```
awk '/Jan 26/ {getline;print $1}' file
13
```

```
awk '/Jan 26/{p=NR+1} NR==p {print $1}' file
13
```

```
awk '{p--} /Jan 26/ {p=1} !p {print $1}' file
13
```